# Ruby with ActiveRecord: open connection to more than 1 SQLite database files

Tags: ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I am working on a Ruby application (*with integration from ActiveRecord to handle database interaction, but it is NOT a full rails app*) that requires handling of 1..n open databases at the same time, where each database is a different specific version of that database. This database is updated every month by a 3rd party, and it is used as a reference for processing other data from other 3rd parties. However, the data being processed could have any one of the most recent 24 (*2 years worth*) versions that needs to be used. So I have a need to be able to open a connection to whichever versions are required simultaneously.

With digging, the only multiple-connection stuff I can find for ActiveRecord would require setting up the database config in database.yml, and creating a set of nearly identical models for each version possible. Having 24 near identical copies of /models and /serializers directories just to handle each version is VERY not DRY, plus I would be at best deleting the oldest 24th config and set of 75 models and 75 serializers and adding the newest set every month, which doesn't make sense to have that workload manually at all.

A fall back I can use is metaprogramming, to dynamically create all 75 models and 75 serializers for each version that is loaded/called, but it seems like there has got to be a better way.

Something like:

```
databases = {
  20210301 = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlite3', database: 'tmp/20210301.sqlite'),
  20210401 = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlite3', database: 'tmp/20210401.sqlite'),
  20210501 = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlite3', database: 'tmp/20210501.sqlite')
}
```

and be able to call upon this db object for queries to it's target DB, separate from other databases connected to.

Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like something that should be handled through database replication and not on the application level and SQLite might not be a good choice.

Comment: How would replication benefit me here, since each DB is static, and distinctly different in the content (although not the structure)?